# Async Function and Readline Using

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to use async function and `readline` same time. After I write to input on `readline`, I want to go to the second thried (`.then`). But it doesn't wait to I write to the text. I want to see `phoneCode` on console but I get `beforeCode`.

```
let phoneCode = "beforeCode";
const asenkronFonksiyon = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

asenkronFonksiyon()
  .then(data => {
    return data;
  })
  .then(data => {
    readline.question(`What's code?`, code => {
      console.log(`Hi ${data}!`);
      phoneCode = code;
      readline.close();
    });
    return phoneCode;
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log("phoneCode" + phoneCode);
  });
```

Comment: Callbacks don't "just work" with promise chains. You have to convert the callback to a promise that resolves within the callback, and `return` that from the continuation in order to prevent from breaking out of the chain.

Comment: do you have any example for that? Because I am new and I couldn't understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline.question` returns immediately. It calls the callback when user input is received. Hence, `return phoneCode` is executed before the phoneCode is updated. You can return a Promise from the second .then block, and call its resolve when the readline callback is called

```
//Other promises
.then(data=>{
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    readline.question(`What's code?`, code => {
      console.log(`Hi ${data}!`);
      readline.close();
      resolve(code);
    });
  });
})
.then(code=>phoneCode=code);
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's start by converting the `readline.question()` method from a callback-based API to a promise-based API:

```
const question = prompt => new Promise(resolve => {
  readline.question(prompt, resolve);
});
```

Now you can return it from the `.then()` continuation in your example:

```
const asenkronFonksiyon = async () => {
  // ...
};

asenkronFonksiyon()
  .then(data => {
    return question(`What's code?`);
  })
  .then(phoneCode => {
    readline.close();
    console.log("phoneCode" + phoneCode);
  });
```

This makes it the same as

```
const asenkronFonksiyon = async () => {
  // ...
};

asenkronFonksiyon()
  .then(data => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      readline.question(`What's code?`, code => {
        resolve(code);
      });
    });
  })
  .then(phoneCode => {
    readline.close();
    console.log("phoneCode" + phoneCode);
  });
```